# User registration and activation email in custom form

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, user-registration, email-verification

I have implemented a custom login and registration form in WP as mentioned [here](http://designmodo.com/wordpress-custom-registration/). User can now register but can not login until admin approves that user from backend.

I need to implement admin notification email for new user registration as well as user notification email admin approves it from backend. I have tried below code in my registration form to send email but that does not seem to work. Moreover the standard email keeps sending.

```
/ Redefine user notification function
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);

        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

        $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your blog %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "\r\n";

        @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

        if ( empty($plaintext_pass) )
            return;

        $message  = __('Hi there,') . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= __('Adios!');

        wp_mail($user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname')), $message);

    }
}
```

For user registration approval I am using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-approve-user/screenshots/) plugin.

How can I send email when user registers using my custom form and notify user when admin approves.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content for email to be sent out to user on new registration on the settings page of WP Approve User plugin. Settings for this plugin is available under Settings menu in WordPress dashboard. Adding content there will do the job sending emails to user after their registration is approved.

If you want to send out emails to Administrator after registration is approved, then you can write a code on the hook `wpau_approve`. This Hook accepts user id as the parameter.

So you can write something like this:

```
add_action ('wpau_approve' , 'send_mail_to_admin_post_approval', 10, 1);

/*
 * Sends email to Administrator after user registration is approved
 * 
 * @param int $user_id User id of user whose registration is just approved
 */
function send_mail_to_admin_post_approval($user_id) {

         $user = new WP_User($user_id);

        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);

        $message  = sprintf(__('New user registration on your blog %s:'), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf(__('E-mail: %s'), $user_email) . "\r\n";

        @wp_mail(get_option('admin_email'), sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname')), $message);
}
```

If even after adding above code in your plugin or theme's functions.php file mails are not going, then we would recommend to install the plugin [Email Log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-log/). After installing that plugin you can view list of all emails triggered by wp_mail function on the page named 'Email Log' under 'Tools' menu in WordPress dashobard. If you see that, your email is being triggered by wp_mail and is not being received by recipients, then this might be issue with your SMTP settings.

You might have to enable or install SMTP software on your server. If you do not have access to it, install [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) plugin and configure it. If WP Mail SMTP plugin is configured correctly, recipients should be able to receive emails which are triggered by wp_mail function after configuring the plugin.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks for responding, but `WP Approve User` plugin has option to send approve and Unapprove  emails. Not sure if they have setting to send email to admin when user registers using my custom registration form.